# the url is stuck at idtoken in msal?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

When I try to implement msal in angular 8 it was working well in local but when deployed the url is struck at idtoken as `https://192.168.0.xxx:xxx/#/id_token` and the handleRedirectCallback function is not working.

Additional: used Redirect method for authentication

How should I proceed with this ?

I used the example from the [msal-angular github repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/msal-angular-samples/angular8-sample-app/src/app/app.component.ts) to implement msal

also saw a blog post with similar issue [here](https://www.shawntabrizi.com/aad/building-a-simple-sign-in-page-with-msal-js-for-microsoft-identities/) but I am not clear with implementing this in angular.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the callback function in separate ts file so I had to add it to app.component.ts to solving this issue.

for more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63195499/14541952)